# Equation involving a modulus and variable in an exponent

Tags: modular-arithmetic, exponential-function

How would I solve for the first positive non-zero integer value for $x$ in this equation?

**Equation:** $1 \equiv 4^x \pmod{199}$

Comment: The number divides $99$. That should cut down on the computation.

Comment: Cool, and thanks for the reformatting. New to the site and haven't figured that out yet. So, are you saying 4^x divides 99 or x divides 99? Also, how did you figure that out?

Comment: The smallest positive $x$ divides $99$. By Fermat's Theorem, $x$ divides $198$. But actually $2^{2x}\equiv 1\pmod{199}$, so by Fermat's Theorem $2x$ divides $198$. Now the search can begin, find $4^{33}$ modulo $199$ using the binary method of modular exponentiation.